# Count number of rows a variable appears in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to count the number of rows that a specific word appears in, and display a table with all the results. Just getting a blank page at the moment.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Set BoatName as variable from the table containing list of boats.

$query = "SELECT BoatName from SpeciesHuntBoats";
$boatname = $conn->query($query);

// Calculate number of rows that boat name appears in another table

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM SpeciesHunt WHERE `BoatName` = '$boatname'");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);


// Display a table showing all boat names and the number of rows that name appears in 

echo "<table><tr><th>Boat Name</th><th>Number of Species</th></tr>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["BoatName"] . "</a></td><td>" . $row["$num_rows"]. "</td>/tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
$conn->close();
```

Comment: A completely blank page sounds like an error.  Turn on PHP error reporting, check your PHP error logs, etc.

Comment: Check in the manual what `$boatname` will be from this line of code `$boatname = $conn->query($query);` and it should be fairly obvious what wrong

Comment: On a side note, never use mysqli_num_rows: it's either [superfluous or harmful](https://phpdelusions.net/top#num_rows). In your case it should be SELECT COUNT(*) query (and a prepared statement of course)

Comment: Error displayed is  Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in .... on line 28

Answer (score 0):

1: in case you have error always check the error logs of your server. that will tell you the exact answer.

2: query returns a mysql_result which you need to further process it.
`$boatname = $conn->query($query);` assigns a mysql_result object to the variable, then
`"SELECT * FROM SpeciesHunt WHERE`BoatName`= '$boatname'"` will try to convert it to string, but will throw an error in php. Probably this is your problem.

Try `$boatname = $conn->query($query)->fetch_object()->BoatName`.
This will fetch the results of the query into an array of objects, then selects the 0th index, then gets the element BoatName.

btw, I don't know your goal here, but the code I supplied will get the boatname from the first row. If there's more than one BoatName and you want to process every of them, you need to put it into a loop.
OR alternatively you can use the following query then put the results into the table

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(SpeciesHunt.id) AS NumberOfSpecies, 
SpeciesHuntBoats.BoatName
FROM SpeciesHunt
LEFT JOIN SpeciesHuntBoats 
    ON SpeciesHuntBoats.BoatName = SpeciesHunt.BoatName
GROUP BY SpeciesHunt.BoatName;
```

then print to a table:

```
echo "<table><tr><th>Boat Name</th><th>Number of Species</th></tr>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["BoatName"] . "</a></td><td>" . $row["NumberOfSpecies"]. "</td>/tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Hello domdetre, you're right - this is the problem line it seems when I look at the error log. Do you know what the line should be instead? I'm trying to build this as a favour for a club I help but struggling! Thank you for your time.

Comment: The reason I didn't answered for the first time is because I assumed you already know what I'm talking about, since you already fetching the results of a query in the while loop.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it's not my area of expertise at all, just trying to remember as much as I can from university days! I've changed the line, though the error is now: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: oops sorry, remove the `[0]`, my bad, I updated the answer.

Comment: never forget that: if you work with php, then php.net is your friend!